# Show that this hyperplane is parallel to the null space of this linear functional.

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-calculus

This is an exercise of my homework of "Functional Analysis".

> If $Y$ is a subspace of a vector space $X$ and $\dim(X/Y)=1$, then every element of $X/Y$ is called a hyperplane parallel to Y. Show that for any linear functional $f\neq 0$ on X, the set $H_1=\{x\in X: f(x)=1\}$ is a hyperplane parallel to the null space $N(f)$ of $f$.

Comment: I don't quite get it: is $\;X/Y\;$ the usual quotient space? Then any element of it is a left coset of the form $\;x+Y\;$ , and thus $\;H_1\;$ is not even a coset and thus not even an element of this quotient $\;X/Y\;$...?

Comment: Is $X/Y$ the usual quotient space? Yes! My "Remember" is wrong... I don't understand your second question, can you detail for me? Thank you!

Comment: An element of a quotient vector space is a left coset, right? $\;H_1\;$ is not a left coset **unless** we take it as a set and *not* as an element of $\;X/Y\;$

Comment: Yes! A element of a quotient vectors space is a left coset. But... taking $H_1$ as a set what we have? I don't see...

Comment: Look at my answer, @Felipe: $\;f(x)\neq 0\implies f(x)\notin H:=\ker f\implies \langle f(x)+H\rangle = X/H\;$ ...

Comment: I don't understand $f(x)\neq 0\Rightarrow f(x)\notin H:=\ker f$. As $\ker f:=\{x\in X: f(x)=1\}$, $\ker f\subseteq Range(f)$ and $f(x)\subseteq Im(f)$

Comment: I think you have a rather huge confussion here: $\;\ker f:=\{x\in X\;;\;f(x)=\color{red}0\}\;$ , **not** $\;f(x)=1\;$... !

Comment: Right! But you said that $H:=\ker f$ and in the exercise $H:=\{x\in X: f(x)=1\}$...

Comment: No @Felipe, in the exercise it is $\;H_{\color{red}1}\;$ , not $\;H\;$ ... Excuse my question: what is your current mathematics level ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the definition of "hyperplane parallel to $N(f)$", we just need to show that $H_1$ is an element of $X/N(f)$, i.e. it is of the form $H_1=x_1+N(f)$ for some vector $x_1\in X$.

First $H_1\neq\emptyset$. In fact, since $f\neq0$ there is $x\in X$ with $f(x)\neq0$. Therefore $f(x)^{-1}x$ satisfies $f(f(x)^{-1}x)=f(x)^{-1}f(x)=1$, i.e. $f(x)^{-1}x\in H_1$.

Let $x_1$ be any element of $H_1$, then we can show that $H_1=x_1+N(f)$. In fact, if $x\in H_1$ then $x=x_1+(x-x_1)$ where $f(x-x_1)=f(x)-f(x_1)=1-1=0$, i.e. $x-x_1\in N(f)$. Conversely, if $y=x_1+x\in x_{1}+N(f)$ then $f(y)=f(x_1+x)=f(x_1)+f(x)=1+0=1$, i.e. $y\in H_1$.

Therefore $H_1$ is one of the cosets in $X/N(f)$, i.e. it is a hyperplane parallel to $N(f)$.

Answer (score -1):

Since $f \neq 0$ on $X$, $H_1$ is not empty. Fix an $x_0 \in H_1$, and consider
the coset $x_0 + N (f).$ Note that this is well-defined irrespective of elements in $H_1$.
Indeed, for any $y \in H_1$, $y \neq x_0$, $y - x_0 \in N (f)$ since $f(y - x_0) = f(y)-f(x_0) =1 - 1 = 0;$ this shows that $x + N (f) = y + N (f)$ for any $x, y \in H_1.$

$1.$ For any $x \in x_0 + N (f)$, there exists an $y \in N (f)$ such that $x = x_0 + y.$
Since $f$ is linear, $f(x) = f(x_0 + y) = f(x_0) + f(y)=1 $ implies $ x \in H_1.$ This
shows that $x_0 + N (f) \subset  H_1.$

$2.$ For any $x \in H_1$, $x = x +0= x + x_0-  x_0 = x_0 + (x - x_0) \in  x_0 + N (f) $ since $f(x - x_0) = f(x)-  f(x_0)=1 - 1 = 0$. This shows that $ H_1 \subset  x_0 + N (f).$
Finally, combining $1.$ and $ 2.$ the inequality gives $H_1 = x_0+N (f)$ and so $H_1$ is one of the cosets in $X/N(f)$, i.e. it is a hyperplane parallel to $N(f)$.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't understand your attempt, so I propose the following:

Since $\;0\neq f\in X^*\;$ , we know $\;H:=\ker f\;$ is a hyperplane or maximal subspace of $\;X\;$ , or in other words: $\;\dim X/H=1\;$ , which means this last vector space is spanned (algebraically, not only topologically) by any non-zero vector $\;\overline v\in X/H\;$.

But clearly $\;\overline v:=f(x)+H\;,\;\;f(x)\neq 0\;$  fulfills the condition...

Comment: "which means this last vector space is spanned (algebraically, not only topologically) by any non-zero vector $\overline{v}\in X/H.$" Can you explain this?

Comment: @Felipe, you tagged your question "Functional Analysis". This seems to indicate you've already studied, among other things, advanced calculus/analysis (both real and complex) and topology, and probably topological vector spaces/groups/rings and etc. One thing is to generate a linear space as such and another to generate a **topological** linear space as such...

Comment: $f(x)$ is a scalar and $H$ is a subspace. You can't add them together.