# Further questions about showing that a hyperplane is parallel to the null space of a linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am trying to understand this question: [Show that this hyperplane is parallel to the null space of this linear functional.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742019/show-that-this-hyperplane-is-parallel-to-the-null-space-of-this-linear-functiona) This is Exercise 2.8.12 from Kreyszig's *Introductory Functional Analysis*.

For one of the answers, the answerer misunderstood the question. The other by Pp.., I'm not able to follow past the second paragraph.

Specifically, I don't get why $f(f(x)^{-1}x) = f(x)^{-1}f(x)$. Actually, I don't think this even makes sense. $f(x)^{-1} \in \text{Im}(f)$, so we can't even apply $f$ to it. If Pp.. meant $f^{-1}(x)$, then I don't think we know $f^{-1}$ even exists. From my understanding, $f^{-1}$ exists iff $f(x)=0 \Rightarrow x=0$, which I don't believe follows from the assumptions.

I understand the goal: show that $H_1 \in X/\mathcal{N}(f)$, meaning $H_1 = x_1 + \mathcal{N}(f)$ for some $x_1 \in X$, but I don't know how to get there from the assumptions:

(1) $f\not = 0$ on $X$ is any linear functional.

(2) $\mathcal{N}(f)$ is a subspace of $X$

(3) codim$\mathcal{N}(f)=1$ (Equivalently dim$(X/\mathcal{N}(f))=1$)

Please help me understand what I'm missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your questions about $f(x)^{-1}$ are based on wrong interpretation of the symbol. It was supposed to mean $\frac 1 {f(x)}$ and not the inverse! Coming to the proof I will use (3) only indirectly, so no mention of it is made in this proof. Suppose $H_1=\{x:f(x)=1\}$. By (1) there exists u such that $f(u) \neq 0$. I will take $x_1 =\frac 1 {f(u)} u$. We have to show that $H_1=x_1+N(f)$. Take $x \in H_1$. Then $f(x-\frac {f(x)} {f(u)} u)=0$ by linearity of f. Let $v=x-\frac {f(x)} {f(u)} u$ so $v \in N(f)$. We have $x=\frac {f(x)} {f(u)} u+v =x_1 +v$ since $f(x)=1$. We have proved that $x \in x_1 +N(f)$. Thus $H_1 \subset x_1 +N(f)$. The reverse inclusion is much simpler and I will leave that to you. Hence $H_1 = x_1 +N(f)$.

Comment: Okay, so the part with $f(x)^{-1}$ is like saying we have some scalar $\lambda$ applied to $u$, and $\lambda$ exists since $f(u) \not = 0$. So $x_1$ is just some arbitrary element of $X$ but we named it nicely.

Comment: And then the proof proceeds to show equivalence of $H_1$ and $x_1 + \mathcal{N}(f)$ by showing inclusion both ways.

So then the next part should be: Let $x \in x_1 + \mathcal{N}(f)$. Then $x = x_1 + v$, for some $v \in \mathcal{N}(f)$. We see $f(x)=f(x_1)+f(v)=1+0$. Thus $x \in H_1$.

Comment: Could you explain where (3) is used, even indirectly? Also, I think I'm confused about what codim$\mathcal{N}(f)=1$ means. If dim$(X/\mathcal{N}(f))=1$, then is there only one coset, $X$? Which means $X/\mathcal{N}(f) = X/\{0\} = \{X\}$?

Then $\mathcal{N}(f) = \{0\}$?

Comment: Actually 1) implies 3). Codimension of N(f)=1 means that if you take any two elements $x+N(f)$ and $y+N(f)$ in $X/N(f)$ then one is a multiple of the other; $y+N(f)=c(x+N(f)$ means $y-cx \in N(f)$ or $f(y-cx)=0$. If $x+N(f) \neq 0$ then x is not in $N(f)$, so $f(x) \neq 0$. We can always choose c such that $f(y-cx) =0$: just take $c=\frac {f(y)} {f(x)}$. That is why 1) implies 3) and there is no need to use 3) explicitly.